# Insert Calendar using Google API (Python)

Tags: python, insert, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to use the Google API to insert a secondary calendar. I've used the Google explanation but can't seem to do it myself. How do you use:

```
calendar = {
'summary': 'calendarSummary',
'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}

 created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()

 print created_calendar['id']
```

Comment: Can we ask you about the error, scopes and the condition of calendar API?

Comment: try:
        import argparse
        flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=
    [tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    except ImportError:
    flags = None

    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
    store = file.Storage('storage.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
              if flags else tools.run(flow, store)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to add a secondary calendar this is the curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer here_add_access_token"  https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars -d {'summary':'here_calendar_name'}
```

And in Python is:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars

headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': "Bearer access_token"
    }
payload = {
        'summary': 'Google Calendar secondary',
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
response = response.text
```